# Meteor - This domain has already been used on Galaxy

Tags: meteor, dns, subdomain, meteor-galaxy

I'm trying to deploy my meteor app to Galaxy to a new subdomain, let's call it xxx.mydomain.com. I'm getting the following console output:

```
Talking to Galaxy servers at https://galaxy.meteor.com
Error deploying application: This domain has already been used on Galaxy. [xxx.mydomain.com]
```

I don't have an app with this domain, my guess is someone else is using it? How do I fix this? I tried looking up this error but nothing shows up on Google and Meteor docs don't seem to help either.

Comment: This is probably the case, but I would approach Galaxy support for this one.

Comment: Thanks, any chance you have an idea how to get in touch with them? They don't seem to have any contact email unless you're willing to spend 1,299$/month on paid support :/

Comment: This should no longer be the case. Normal support should now be [available for everyone](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/support.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've opened a ticket with them